# Div transparent through parent div up to grandparent div background

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a wrapper div class="wrapper" in the middle of a image background in a HTML document. On top of that div there is another one of class="inner". How to make the inner div transparent, so that it cuts through his parent div, and we can finaly see the actual background image ?

```
<body> 
<image style="height:100%; "/>
    <div class="wrapper" style="background:green;">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is a example inside codepen:
https://codepen.io/kenshin30/pen/JjjMGbm

How to make the pink div transparent so we can see the actual background image not the green div?

I just want to mention, that the wrapper div is meant to be a React Video Player, and the inner div is a Slider Gallery. When component is not hovered, and the Video Player is not activated, the inner div is meant to be transparent, but not show the disabled Video Player below, but the main image on the background.

Comment: It depends what the green div contains.
The easiest way would be to remove the "wrapper" div and to apply a big fat green border to "inner"

Comment: in the actual app , the wrapper div becomes actually a React Player displaying a video when hovered, and the inner wrap becomes a slick-slider when hovered . Case is when not hovered, i want to see the background throught this div, so border is not what i'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can't make an element transparent by placing another transparent element over it.
But you could remove one of the elements and give the transparent element a border to give the same appearance.

https://codepen.io/jaredroder/pen/YzzYqLZ

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.back-image {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 100px solid green;
  background: transparent;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="back-image">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556740758-90de374c12ad?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" alt="">
  <div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As i mentioned, the wrapper div is a React Player component, and inner div is Gallery Slider. When hovered, the Slider is meant to play image slides but else it is meant to be transparent and  show the background image

Comment: Okay, but it doesn't really matter *what* the components/elements are, you can't force an opaque element to lose opacity by placing a transparent element over it. Opacity doesn't work like that with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `opacity` style attribute:

```html
<body> 
<image style="height:100%; "/>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner" style="opacity:0.5">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: If i add opacity to inner div, it will just become more green since it's direct parent background color is green and i don't want that. I want to see part of the  background image not the wrapper. I put a slight edit to the post so it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where I wanted to see the background of `body` while inside of another `div` with white background.

I use:

```
mix-blend-mode: multiply;
```

inside my inner `div` and it works fine.

[mix-blend-mode (w3-schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playdemo.php?filename=playcss_mix-blend-mode&preval=multiply)